# HTML5, ES6 template string polyfill

Tags: javascript, html, es6-shim

For our application we need to use new feature [`template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
var verLongKey= `834r845784576485
y84ery5845y485yu843
483y53485684576845
jhu87843647356756745==457485,mh
ererthe8t0998785==ery8`;
```

But old browsers(like android default browsers) don't support template string.

How can I get polyfill for this feature?
Tried [`babel`](https://github.com/JasonBerry/babel-es6-polyfill). We got this polyfill working for all features but `template string`.
Currently using [`modernizr`](https://modernizr.com/download?templatestrings-setclasses) to detect support and show alert to use other browser.
This approach is annoying for users. How can i get some polyfill to make this work on the non supporting browsers?

What made us this `template strings`.
The problem is i can't use these tools(`trceur`,`babel`) as this file is generated on the production from `puppet`. There is no way we will run these transpilers there. want to add some polyfill on the browser side. the key contains some `\n` characters in it need to preserve those. I want some polyfill so, i can include before the configs js file.

Comment: What makes you "need" template strings? You can do everything pretty easily without them too, you know...

Comment: @MadaraUchiha agree, same result can be achieved with ES5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35695834/1092711

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Having to backport a lot of code which uses template strings extensively is *not* fun, considering that the use of templates allows dynamically templated code embedded in strings (Javascript, SQL, etc.) to actually be readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Michael But he isn't backporting, he's looking for a polyfill, meaning he currently isn't using it, but wants to. Also, Using template strings for SQL is a [**really** bad idea](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 main ES6 polyfills that can give you template string support but none of them have full support as you can see at [kangax's ECMAScript support table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

- Traceur - This is Google's ECMAScript polyfill that support some ECMAScript 6 and ECMAScript next features, it have 4/5 support for template strings, there is no toString conversion.
- Babel - Another ECMAScript polyfill, have more support in general but also have only 4/5 support for template strings, also no toString conversion.
- es6-shim - I'm not sure if it's even developed anymore, but it doesn't have template strings anyway.

But you might want to think twice before using template string, it just a syntactic sugar for string with + to add variables and \ to have multi lines.

Comment: The problem is i can't use these tools as this file is generated on the production from `puppet`. There is no way we will run these transpilers there. want to add some polyfill on the browser side. the key contains some `\n` characters in it need to preserve those. I want some polyfill so, i can include before the configs js file.

Comment: I know this is syntactic sugar. But the way unix read file and the `pupper` replace the keys, needed some way to preserve `\n` characters. `template string` was the solution.

Comment: Traceur and Babel are *transpilers*, not polyfills. Running them clientside might be possible but is not recommended.

Comment: The "syntactic sugar" of template strings looks much nicer than escaping every newline with `\ `, or mass concatenation with `+`. Especially when you need to insert variables inside said string.

Comment: I would also note it's not really "sugar" if you have no control over the strings or how many newlines they will contain, in which case escaping is not possible...