# Materializecss.com carousel only js needed

Tags: javascript, module, carousel, materialize

I am using https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize this one, latest 1.0.0-alpha.2 release version **How I can grab carousel only js?**
I am trying to import just one js module (carousel). Your full minified file is too heavy for me. I've tryied to take just carousel.js and facing error Uncaught

```
ReferenceError: cash is not defined
```

Next step was adding cash.js insides, and I've got such error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined
```

I recognize your "core" is global.js file? I've added it and all seemed be work, but now I am facing ES6 errors in IE11. But not with full minimized version of your file. Ok,

```
jQuery.error(`Method ${methodOrOptions} does not exist on jQuery.${pluginName}`);
```

this row could be removed, but I have other error is

```
syntax error class Carousel {
```

Here I've stucked...

**So the question is: what minimal list of js files I should add for correct work of your carousel?**

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to Bootstrap that let's you compile and build a subset of its functionality if you are not 100% fixed on Materialize. Its quite simple and straightforward and can be done on their page then downloaded.

A good place to start:

[customize your BS](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/)

Look into what you need in:

- [CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/)
- [Components](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/)

If you are sticking with original question I would suggest you post relevant code AND use popper indentation, punctuation to make everything more readable.

Comment: sorry, my question was not fully describe the situation. Now updated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that awesome guys uses mixed up es5, es6 code and typescript. Template string, has not got full support polyfill, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694708/html5-es6-template-string-polyfill)

So I just rewrite typescript code with [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and rewrite es6 to es5 with Traceur. Now all works fine even IE